# How to downgrade gnome shell 3.5 to 3.4

Tags: gnome

Question is simple. I noticed that there are almost no extensions for gnome 3.5. What to do?

Comment: gnome 3.5? What ubuntu version are you using? Its gnome from some PPA o from repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here is how to get a extension to work in a version of Gnome Shell.

You can usually download the extensions as zips - look for the github link on the relevant [extension page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/):
[image]

Press Download Zip:

[image]

and extract the zip file into `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Look inside the extracted folder for the `metadata.json` file:
[image]

and edit it in a text editor:
[image]

add this line inside the "shell-version" brackets, with your shell version.:

```
   [3.5],
```

[image]

and then select and copy the UUID, save and exit the text editor.

Go back to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and rename the folder you  just extracted to the copied UUID - Right Click > Rename > Paste *(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)*.

You should hopefully then be able to enable it in [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/).

Hope this works - seems to work for Gnome 3.8 & 3.10